# Java: Relative path to external text file

Tags: java, file, text, path, relative-path

I am a bit confused with path in Java (using Eclipse). This is my file structure:

```
 Folder

    Subfolder

        file.txt

    jarfile.jar
```

So, I am trying to make the jar file parse data from file.txt and I use the following code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./Subfolder/file.txt"));
```

I have made a runnable jar file with Eclipse, put it in the Folder, but it does not work. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful - but I sometimes need to check where my code is running from to work out relative paths so I just do `(new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use a resource file via a `Class` object, the path to the resource must be absolute:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Subfolder/file.txt");
```

Note that doing what you do is a bad idea, that is, opening a scanner on a resource which you don't have a reference to:

```
new Scanner(someInputStreamHere());
```

you have no reference to that input stream, therefore you cannot close it.

What is more, `.getResource*()` return `null` if the resource does not exist; in this case you'll get an NPE!

Recommended if you use Java 6 (using Guava's Closer):

```
final URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource");

if (url == null) // Oops... Resource does not exist
    barf();

final Closer closer = Closer.create();
final InputStream in;
final Scanner scanner;

try {
    in = closer.register(url.openStream());
    scanner = closer.register(new Scanner(in));
    // do stuff
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw closer.rethrow(e);
} finally {
    closer.close();
}
```

If you use Java 7, just use a try-with-resources statement:

```
final URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource");

if (url == null) // Oops... Resource does not exist
    barf();

final InputStream in;
final Scanner scanner;

try (
    in = url.openStream();
    scanner = new Scanner(in);
) {
    // do stuff
} catch (IOException e) {
    // deal with the exception if needed; or just declare it at the method level
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example because java is platform independent look at getting the relative absolute or canonical path as needed I hope this gives you an idea of what to do.

```
/**
 * This method reads the AcronymList.xlsx and is responsible for storing historical acronyms
 * and definitions.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws InvalidFormatException 
 */
public file readAcronymList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    String accListFile = new File("src\\org\\alatecinc\\acronymfinder\\dal\\acIgnoreAddList\\AcronymList.xlsx").getCanonicalPath();
    File acFile = new File(accListFile).getAbsoluteFile();
    return acFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

Scanner in = new Scanner( getClass().getResource("Subfolder/file.txt"));

Comment: Nope... `.getResource()` returns a URL

Answer (score 0):

Why resource?  Is the txt file embedded in the Jar file?  It will load the file from the jar.

Just use a File or FileInputStream with the path you already put.